# Long key press GTK

Tags: c, linux, windows, gtk, cross-platform

A short time ago I encountered a problem with a long keypress. I'm developing GTK application and having some logic based on key pressing and key releasing. I know how to handle it, but I get unexpected behavior pressing letter buttons. A key release event is triggered when a key is still pushed down and it happens with Windows only. It doesn't happen With Linux (Kubuntu & Arch linux (KDE)). Is this bug or should I consider the behavior with the application logic?

Here code goes

```c
#include <gtk/gtk.h>

int release_count = 0;

static gboolean 
key_event_cb(GtkWidget *widget, GdkEventKey *event, gpointer data)
{
  printf("Key released %d\n", release_count);
  ++release_count;
  return FALSE;
}

static void
activate(GtkApplication* app, gpointer user_data)
{
  GtkWidget *window;

  window = gtk_application_window_new(app);
  gtk_window_set_title(GTK_WINDOW(window), "Window");
  gtk_window_set_default_size(GTK_WINDOW(window), 200, 200);
  gtk_widget_add_events(window, GDK_KEY_RELEASE_MASK | GDK_KEY_PRESS_MASK);
  g_signal_connect(
    window, "key-release-event", G_CALLBACK(key_event_cb), NULL
  ); //keyboard events
  gtk_widget_show_all(window);
}

int
main(int argc, char **argv)
{
  GtkApplication *app;
  int status;

  app = gtk_application_new("org.gtk.example", G_APPLICATION_FLAGS_NONE);
  g_signal_connect(app, "activate", G_CALLBACK(activate), NULL);
  status = g_application_run(G_APPLICATION(app), argc, argv);
  g_object_unref(app);

  return status;
}
```

If you launch the code and press `h` you get a message like `key pressed {counter}` with some delay.
So, is it normal behavior for a key release event? If no, please tell me how to fix it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This happens due to I run my program under VirtualBox. The program works properly if it is launched on Windows as a host system.

Answer (score 0):

Are you running your program by typing `test.exe` and pressing <kbd>return</kbd>?
 If so, it may be registering the <kbd>return</kbd> key release once the program is already running.

You can test this by running your program, but hold the key press until the program is on screen, then release and see if it registers the state change.

Another way is to print `event->hardware_keycode` inside of `key_event_cb`, and press a few keys and see if you can see which keycode of the key presses matches the ghost key press.

If you found it is your <kbd>return</kbd> key causing nuisance, a quick fix could be:

```
static gboolean 
key_event_cb(GtkWidget *widget, GdkEventKey *event, gpointer data)
{
    if (event->keyval != GDK_KEY_Return) {
        printf("Key released %d\n", release_count);
        ++release_count;
    }
    return FALSE;
}
```

Comment: My bad. I forgot to resolve the question. Actually, this happens due to I run my program under VirtualBox. The program works properly if it is launched on Windows as a host system. Should I post it as a solution?

Comment: No problem. I ran into this problem on Ubuntu, happening at random on separate runs. Sure, post the solution if you feel it might help future users with this problem.